# Cross origin on iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

My webpage(wp1) has an iframe. The source of the iframe is another webpage(wp2). I have some javascript functions on wp1 which try to manipulate the contents of wp2. However , the browser gives "  Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame." How can i get around this?

Comment: @C0dekid — That won't help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the MDN page about postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), if your parent and child domains differ only by a subdomain (e.g `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`), you can set `document.domain` to the same value on both pages and it should be enough to get it to work.

Accepted value for `document.domain` is that of the superdomain (`example.com` = ok, `subdomain.example.com` = nope), according to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).